# Laravel-5.8: Trying to get property 'display_name' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am getting a "Trying to get property 'display_name' of non-object" error in Laravel when I try assessing a data from Category model.

I have 2 models: Post and Category; for which I have their corresponding tables:
`Posts('id', 'title', 'body', 'cover_image')`
and
`Categories('id', 'display_name','name', 'key).`

Pivot Table is: category_post

This is my Post Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'posts';


    //Model Relationships

    public function tag(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'id');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','id');
    }
}
```

Here is my Category Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

//Model Relationships

    public function post() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'id');
    }

}
```

Also, this is my PagesController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if ( !is_null(Post::class) ) {    
            $posts = Post::latest()->with('category')->paginate(5);

            return view('pages.index')->with(['posts' => $posts]);
        }
        else {
            return view('pages.empty');
        }
    }
```

And this is my blade file:

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
   @foreach($posts as $post)
      <span> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> {{ $post->category->display_name }} </span>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

UPDATES

These are my migrations:
Posts Table:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->nullable();
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->string('cover_image')->default('noimage.jpg')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

And my Categories Table:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('display_name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

The intended result is to get the display_name from the from the categories table and display them in a list manner.
This is the Error I keep getting

> Trying to get property 'display_name' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)

I tried calling it this way:

```
<span> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> {{ $post->category()->display_name }} </span>
```

But it also doesn't work.

---

### EDIT:

After dumping the $post variable in the Controller:

```
Post {#331 ▼
  #table: "posts"
  #fillable: array:7 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "title"
    2 => "slug"
    3 => "body"
    4 => "cover_image"
    5 => "user_id"
    6 => "category_id"
  ]
  +primaryKey: "id"
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "This is a Base Announcement"
    "slug" => null
    "body" => "Please feel free to delete this announcement and create a new one afterwards."
    "cover_image" => "noimage.jpg"
    "user_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2019-05-20 14:22:45"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-20 14:22:45"
    "category_id" => null
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "This is a Base Announcement"
    "slug" => null
    "body" => "Please feel free to delete this announcement and create a new one afterwards."
    "cover_image" => "noimage.jpg"
    "user_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2019-05-20 14:22:45"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-20 14:22:45"
    "category_id" => null
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you must insert the foreign key "category_id" on you model and table "posts"

Comment: `$post->category->pivot->display_name`?

Comment: @Diego Ive added the foreign key to the table; but how do I add it to the Model?

Comment: @quickSwap Please I don't get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not saving the **CATEGORY_ID** in your posts table, save well the category ID and try like this:

**Update POST model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'posts';

    // Setup fields of table "posts"
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'title', 'body', 'cover_image','category_id'];

    //Model Relationships
    public function tag(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'id');
    }
    // Relation category to foreign key 
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id');
    }
}
```

**Category Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    // Setup fields of table "category"
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'display_name', 'name', 'key'];

    //Model Relationships
    public function posts() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}
```

**View**

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
   @foreach($posts as $post)
      <span> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> {{ $post->category->display_name }} </span>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

**Migration Posts - Foreign key category_id**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

            // Your other fields.....

            // You must setup category like this
            $table->integer('category_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        if (!empty($posts)) {  

            // Please let me know this test
            dd($posts[0]->category->display_name);
            return view('pages.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
        }
        else {
            return view('pages.empty');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Moreover, when I die and dump the {{dd($post)}}, under the categories relation, I get null. Please if there's anything I can add, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Post your migration please

Comment: Please explain what you've changed instead of posting code only - this helps the OP (and others) to learn from your changes!

Comment: Okay. But I think you're missing the '$' sign to your posts variable in your "if condition". It's throwing an error: "undefined constant posts"

Comment: but even after correcting that, I still get the same "Trying to get property 'display_name' of non-object" error. Hmmm

Comment: I updated CONTROLLER with a test var dump. Please let me know. However you must check if CATEGORY ID exist on your table categories.

Comment: @ Diego i don't think it worked either. It went straight to the error page. but if I should dump the $post[0] it displays this the table data.

Comment: "category_id" Is NULL, you are not saving the category ID on post table. we found the issue :)

Comment: Whew! this has really bogged me. Can you please update your answer? :) Thanks

Comment: If you have PhpMyAdmin set manually category_id on posts table with ID "1" and try again it would be work

Comment: if you fixed you can check as OK my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you make a mistake in `post()` method in your `Category` model. Try to modify this method like this:

Category Model:

```php
public function post() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'id');
}
```

Source: [Eloquent-relationship one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)